# String.replace regex to convert "${anyVariable} in a ${string}" to ":anyVariable in a :string"

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression to replace unresolved velocity variables with the syntax required by other parameterized variable frameworks such as spring jdbc and hibernate. 
Essentially, I want a replacement pattern to find and replace ${a} with :a, ${b} with :b, etc.

Comment: What language are you using? Regex has many different incompatible dialects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generic regex syntax since you didn't specify a language:

```
/\$\{([^}]+)}/:\1/g
/\$\{(.+?)}/:\1/g  # same thing in this case
```

Comment: :) I was curious about the perl compatible regex, but actual language is java. Working Test case is:

System.out.println(
"${a} and ${b}".replaceAll(
"\\$\\{([^}]+)}", ":$1"));

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\${(.*?)}/:$1/g;
```

Will answer the question as stated.

Whether it solves your problem or not, I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what environment you're in, but the pattern should be `$\{([^}])+\}` and you should replace it with `:$1`